# Creating a Unity UI slider logic to manipulate the Fog discretely, where the fog will be set active after certain duration and increment with slider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

So, I created a game, where I need to simulate fog. The fog is supposed to be displayed when rain >= 50 mm. I implemented the logic as follows, please refer the part where I commented as *//What needs to be added here so as the Fog will start to be displayed at rain >= 50 on "_slider" slider*

P.s., the block:

```
 public void _FogIntensity(float newHeightDensity)
        {
            heightDensity = newHeightDensity;
        }
```

is used in the file "GlobalFog.cs" and function **"public void SliderLogic()"** , given below: to control the Fog Intensity with respect to slider, I need to activate the slider when rain count >=50 mm; else, not.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using static UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects.GlobalFog;



namespace UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent (typeof(Camera))]
    [AddComponentMenu ("Image Effects/Rendering/Global Fog")]
    class GlobalFog : PostEffectsBase
    {
        [SerializeField] private Slider _slider;
        [SerializeField] private Slider _sliderFog;
        [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _sliderText;
        [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI WarnText;
        [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI Subtitles;
        [Tooltip("Apply distance-based fog?")]
        public bool  distanceFog = true;
        [Tooltip("Exclude far plane pixels from distance-based fog? (Skybox or clear color)")]
        public bool  excludeFarPixels = true;
        [Tooltip("Distance fog is based on radial distance from camera when checked")]
        public bool  useRadialDistance = false;
        [Tooltip("Apply height-based fog?")]
        public bool  heightFog = true;
        [Tooltip("Fog top Y coordinate")]
        public float height = 1.0f;
        [Range(0.001f,10.0f)]
        public float heightDensity = 1.0f;
        [Tooltip("Push fog away from the camera by this amount")]
        public float startDistance = 0.0f;

        public Shader fogShader = null;
        private Material fogMaterial = null;


        public override bool CheckResources ()
        {
            CheckSupport (true);

            fogMaterial = CheckShaderAndCreateMaterial (fogShader, fogMaterial);

            if (!isSupported)
                ReportAutoDisable ();
            return isSupported;
        }

        [ImageEffectOpaque]
        void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
        {
            if (CheckResources() == false || (!distanceFog && !heightFog))
            {
                Graphics.Blit(source, destination);
                return;
            }

            Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
            Transform camtr = cam.transform;

            Vector3[] frustumCorners = new Vector3[4];
            cam.CalculateFrustumCorners(new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), cam.farClipPlane, cam.stereoActiveEye, frustumCorners);
            var bottomLeft = camtr.TransformVector(frustumCorners[0]);
            var topLeft = camtr.TransformVector(frustumCorners[1]);
            var topRight = camtr.TransformVector(frustumCorners[2]);
            var bottomRight = camtr.TransformVector(frustumCorners[3]);

            Matrix4x4 frustumCornersArray = Matrix4x4.identity;
            frustumCornersArray.SetRow(0, bottomLeft);
            frustumCornersArray.SetRow(1, bottomRight);
            frustumCornersArray.SetRow(2, topLeft);
            frustumCornersArray.SetRow(3, topRight);

            var camPos = camtr.position;
            float FdotC = camPos.y - height;
            float paramK = (FdotC <= 0.0f ? 1.0f : 0.0f);
            float excludeDepth = (excludeFarPixels ? 1.0f : 2.0f);
            fogMaterial.SetMatrix("_FrustumCornersWS", frustumCornersArray);
            fogMaterial.SetVector("_CameraWS", camPos);
            fogMaterial.SetVector("_HeightParams", new Vector4(height, FdotC, paramK, heightDensity * 0.5f));
            fogMaterial.SetVector("_DistanceParams", new Vector4(-Mathf.Max(startDistance, 0.0f), excludeDepth, 0, 0));

            var sceneMode = RenderSettings.fogMode;
            var sceneDensity = RenderSettings.fogDensity;
            var sceneStart = RenderSettings.fogStartDistance;
            var sceneEnd = RenderSettings.fogEndDistance;
            Vector4 sceneParams;
            bool linear = (sceneMode == FogMode.Linear);
            float diff = linear ? sceneEnd - sceneStart : 0.0f;
            float invDiff = Mathf.Abs(diff) > 0.0001f ? 1.0f / diff : 0.0f;
            sceneParams.x = sceneDensity * 1.2011224087f; // density / sqrt(ln(2)), used by Exp2 fog mode
            sceneParams.y = sceneDensity * 1.4426950408f; // density / ln(2), used by Exp fog mode
            sceneParams.z = linear ? -invDiff : 0.0f;
            sceneParams.w = linear ? sceneEnd * invDiff : 0.0f;
            fogMaterial.SetVector("_SceneFogParams", sceneParams);
            fogMaterial.SetVector("_SceneFogMode", new Vector4((int)sceneMode, useRadialDistance ? 1 : 0, 0, 0));

            int pass = 0;
            if (distanceFog && heightFog)
                pass = 0; // distance + height
            else if (distanceFog)
                pass = 1; // distance only
            else
                pass = 2; // height only
            Graphics.Blit(source, destination, fogMaterial, pass);
        }

        //Changes made in the below line
        public void _FogIntensity(float newHeightDensity)
        {
            heightDensity = newHeightDensity;
        }
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        public void SliderLogic()
        {

            _slider.onValueChanged.AddListener((v) =>
            {
                _sliderText.text = v.ToString("0.0") + "mm/hour";


                //On case of moderate Rain
                else if (_slider.value >= 2 && _slider.value <= 10)
                {
                    WarnText.text = "Moderate Rainfall";
                    Subtitles.SetText("(Take out your umbrellas.)");

                }

                //In case if Heavy Rain
                else if (_slider.value >= 10 && _slider.value <= 50)
                {
                    WarnText.text = "Heavy Showers";
                    Subtitles.SetText("(Orange Alert; Exercise Caution!.)");

                }
                //In case if Extreme Downpour
                else if (_slider.value >= 50 || (_sliderFog.value > 0))
                {
                    WarnText.text = "Violent Showers";
                    Subtitles.SetText("(Heavy precipitation. Do not venture out unless absolutely necessary!.)");
                    //What needs to be added here so as the Fog will start to be displayed at rain >= 50 on "_slider" slider
          
                }

            });
        }

    }
   
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Unity HDRP?

Comment: @MickyD, I did considered the point for HDRP; However presuming by the fact that I wanted to exclusively build for AR, I thought HDRP would be too heavy on hardware resources; plus not many devices support multithreading for ARCore.

Comment: Ah, this is for `AR`.  I've added the tag for you.  Good luck. :)